# How to avoid particular interaction in python loop ? I want to skip 3 7 and 9 as mentioned code but it remove only 3

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if i!= (3 or 7 or 9) :
        print(i)
    else:
        continue
```

** I want to skip 3 7 and 9 as mentioned code but it remove only 3**.

Comment: `if i not in (3, 7, 9):`

Comment: The value of `(3 or 7 or 9)` is simply `3`.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if i!= 3 and i!= 7 and i!=9 :
        print(i)
    else:
        continue
```